# Convert from String to Int Issue

Tags: swift, xcode

After I upgrade Xcode from 10.1 to 10.2
My code doesn't work as expected anymore.
After debugging, I find out the code below doesn't work as it was

```
let divinfo = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
var parse = divinfo.components(separatedBy: " ") // ["512", "50,425,550", "100,850,1100", "200,1700,2200", "400,3400,4400", ""]
```

After that, I want to remove the first item from `parse` and parse it to Int

```
let firstItem = parse.removeFirst()
print(firstItem) // <----
print(Array(firstItem)) // <-----
guard let base = Int(firstItem) else { return nil } // Xcode 10.2 return the func here but Xcode 10.1 still working
```

The strange part is output from 2 print lines, I convert the `firstItem` to `Array`

```
512
["", "5", "1", "2"]
```

This might is the reason why the function returns nil.
Anyone get the same issue or can give me any explanation?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your data or rather it is not the same as you show here. For me the code works and when doing the last print I don't have the first "" element. Most likely the "512" element starts with some invisible character that makes the `Int()` call fail.

Comment: can you try by removing white spaces ? firsItem.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

Comment: I tried, but the output still the same

Comment: Did you clean the project and rebuild?

Comment: The output ["", "5", "1", "2"] isn't strange. It happens when you convert a string to an Array<T>.